netsh mbn add profile interface="Mobile" name="Cellular.xml" command fails with "Profile cannot be loaded" error
I'm in the process of adding a cellular profile using netsh commands to a tablet device running Windows 10.I'm using the following XML to load the profile. But fails to load profile. Please help me if you have any idea on this. So that I can load the profile successfully.Tried to run the netsh commands, but failed to load the profile. But could not load.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MBNProfileExt xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WWAN/profile/v4">
    <Name>Mobile</Name>
    <IsDefault>false</IsDefault>
    <SimIccID>89441000304066880000</SimIccID>
    <AutoConnectOnInternet>false</AutoConnectOnInternet>
</MBNProfileExt>
<ModemDMConfigProfile>
    <Name>Mobile</Name>
    <SimIccID>89441000304066880000</SimIccID>
    <ApnID></ApnID>
    <OemConnectionId>4D4EFF29-EDF4-4C81-8981-9ECBD1130606</OemConnectionId>
    <RoamApplicability>AllRoaming</RoamApplicability>
    <Context></Context>
    <AdminEnable>True</AdminEnable>
    <AdminRoamControl>AllRoamAllowed</AdminRoamControl>
</ModemDMConfigProfile>


Your XML is not well formed.  Well Formed means there is only one root tag.  You have two root tags.  The xml is valid but many libraries give exceptions when the xml is not well formed.

Well it's a well formed XML fragment not an XML document. The docs say "This outermost (document) element may not be contained by any other elements." so each on needs to go in a separate XML https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/mbn/element-modemdmconfigprofile#parent-elements
